# Indexing into matrix with logical array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A`, which is `m x n`. What I want to do is count the number of `NaN` elements in a row. If the number of `NaN` elements is greater than or equal to some arbitrary threshold, then all the values in that row will set to `NaN`.

```
num_obs = sum(isnan(rets), 2);
index = num_obs >= min_obs;
```

Like I say I am struggling to get my brain to work. Being trying different variations of the line below but no luck.

```
rets(index==0, :) = rets(index==0, :) .* NaN;
```

The Example data for `threshold >= 1` is:

```
A = [-7 -8 1.6 11.9;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   5.5 6.3 2.1 NaN;
   5.5 4.2 2.2 5.6;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN];
```

and the result I want is:

```
A = [-7 -8 1.6 11.9;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN;
   5.5 4.2 2.2 5.6;
   NaN NaN NaN NaN];
```

Comment: try this `rets(index, :) = NaN;`

Comment: For example if you want your row to be = NaN if there is at least 2 NaN in the row: `M(sum(isnan(M),2)>=2,:) = NaN`

Comment: @obchardon that makes sense to me however it keeps turning my matrix A into NaN's everywhere

Comment: It works well on my computer, are you sure that you count the nan according to the row and not to the column ?

Comment: Yeh must be something I'm missing. The count is working on the row though not the column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
A = magic(4);A(3,3)=nan;
threshold=1;

for ii = 1:size(A,1) % loop over rows
    if sum(isnan(A(ii,:)))>=threshold % get the nans, sum the occurances
        A(ii,:)=nan(1,size(A,2)); % fill the row with column width amount of nans
    end
end
```

Results in

```
A =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     4    14    15     1
```

Or, as [@Obchardon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809770/indexing-into-matrix-with-logical-array/41809939#comment70807664_41809770) mentioned in his comment you can vectorise:

```
A(sum(isnan(A),2)>=threshold,:) = NaN

A =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     4    14    15     1
```

As a side-note you can easily change this to columns, simply do all indexing for the other dimension:

```
A(:,sum(isnan(A),1)>=threshold) = NaN;
```

Comment: the vectorise way turns my matrix A all NaN, which I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `isnan` function, you can use `A ~= A` for extracting `NaN` elements.

```
A(sum((A ~= A),2) >= t,:) = NaN
```

where `t` is the *threshold* for the minimum number of existing `NaN` elements.

Comment: You edited the question to contain a syntactically correct MATLAB matrix, but you missed the opening square bracket in both cases. I would have rejected that edit, as editing code in questions is not-done, apart from indentation. See [this meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). Please don't edit code again, but keep up the good work in grammar/spelling etc!

Comment: @Adriaan, I see, I forgot to put the opening square brackets. I could've been more careful about it! I'll keep your hint in mind! Thanks for the tip!